# Remove the columns in media library

Tags: media-library, columns

How can i disable/remove the columns for Media Library? I want for **author** and **comments** column.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hook for these columns is `manage_media_columns`. So just filter the columns here:

```
add_filter( 'manage_media_columns', 'wpse_77687_remove_media_columns' );

function wpse_77687_remove_media_columns( $columns )
{
    unset( $columns['author'] );
    unset( $columns['comments'] );
    return $columns;
}
```

Comment: I can put in the field `unset` another columns like : `dates`. etc.. Many thanks, works!